# C# Custom Exception non-invocable or type not valid

Tags: c#, exception

I have a separate project in my solution, a library (seclib.dll), for handling custom error messages.
This is the whole contents

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace seclib
{
    public class Exception : System.Exception
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class FileNotFound : IOException
        {            
            public FileNotFound() { }
            public FileNotFound(string message)
                : base(message) { }
            public FileNotFound(string message, Exception inner)
                : base(message, inner) { }
        }

        public class ProcessException : ApplicationException
        {
            public ProcessException() { }
            public ProcessException(string message)
                : base(message) { }
            public ProcessException(string message, Exception inner)
                : base(message, inner) { }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to use it from my main project in the solution (reference exists), like

```
        try
        {
            //some code here:
            //1. try open a non existing file -> File not found
            //2. I read the file but is empty, or I dont recognise contents -> Process exception manually
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            throw seclib.Exception.FileNotFound("file error message", e);
        }
        catch (System.ApplicationException e)
        {
            throw seclib.Exception.ProcessException("some other error message", e);
        }
```

I have the error (before compile) "class seclib.Exception.FileNotFound" (or, ProcessException in the second catch) and "Non-invocable member 'Exception.FileNotFound cannot be used as a method' (same for next catch, i.e. Exception.ProcessException.. etc).
If I delete the parenthesis i.e. used it as throw seclib.Exception.FileNotFound; etc., I receive 'Exception.FileNotFound' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.

Could someone please help me? Thank you very much

Comment: throw new seclib.Exception.FileNotFound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new *instance* of the exception you want to throw:

```
// notice the "new" keyword
throw new seclib.Exception.FileNotFound("file error message", e);
```

---

### Is `Exception` right?

The constuctors defined for `FileNotFound` and `ProcessException` currently take an inner `Exception` as an argument, but `Exception` in that scope refers to the enclosing `seclib.Exception` class - change the constructor signatures to:

```
public FileNotFound(string message, System.Exception inner)  // System.Exception will resolve to the type you expect
            : base(message, inner) { }
```

---

### Are your `catch` expressions right?

Since `FileNotFound` and `ProcessException` inherit from the base types you're currently catching, you might end up nesting either *multiple times* - maybe you'll want to test for that:

```
try {

}
catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
{
    if(e is seclib.Exception.FileNotFound)
        // Already wrapped in our custom exception type, re-throw as is
        throw;

    throw new seclib.Exception.FileNotFound("file error message", e);
}
```

or

```
try {

}
catch (seclib.Exception)
{
    // already wrapped, move along
    throw;
}
catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
{
    throw new seclib.Exception.FileNotFound("file error message", e);
}
catch (System.ApplicationException e)
...
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, I need new glasses and a break.. Thank you very much. Just a small clarification: how do I use the 'e'? It throws me a 'cannot convert from System.Exception' to 'seclib.Exception' - I try this: "throw new seclib.Exception.ProcessException("some other error message", e.InnerException);"
Thank you!

Comment: @Nick Change the constructor signatures to refer to `System.Exception inner` instead of `Exception inner` (otherwise it resolves to your custom parent type)

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it.. Much appreciated.